# Logstash connection with SQL Server (SSMS) Issue

Tags: sql-server, database, elasticsearch, connection, logstash

Greeting everyone,
I am having a problem while connecting to Logstash using SSMS. Following is logstash-sample.conf file detail:
[image]

Whenever I try to execute the above config file using shell.It generates an Exception however the issue is only limited towards SSMS, If I change the parameters for MYSQL it works fine. I have tried a number of solutions for Logstash to work with SSMS but none of it worked out.
[image]
I would appreciate if you could help me.
Thank you :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you provide the right path of the driver jar file?

Answer (score 0):

The error states

> No config files found in path D:/Stack/logstash-8.6.1/config/logstash-sample.confclear

I think the problem is that your configuration file is called `logstash-sample.conf` and on your command line you have `... -f logstash-sample.confclear`

Just a typo I think...